# VisualVM profiler is behaving inexplicably, and I'm at a loss. What is happening here?

Tags: java, methods, profiling, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm developing a Java project (it's a mod for Minecraft) and have recently been on an optimisation spree, looking at which parts of the code take up the most time so that I can improve performance. Besides my own code, I'm looking at ways to optimise the default Minecraft code. I'm using VisualVM to profile the methods in the codebase.

I'm no stranger to VisualVM, having used it on several occasions over the past few years to inform a number of successful, significant, and simple optimisations to the game's base code. But this time the profiler's throwing up a result that just doesn't make sense - no matter how I look at it.

According to VisualVM, invocations of a single method (from various points in the code flow) are, collectively, responsible for around 5-10%* of overall tick time during the application loop (results vary over different sampling periods). Must be quite the computation hog, right? The issue is that the method in question is *nothing more than a field reference* :

```
public boolean isInWater()
{
    return this.inWater;
}
```

(This method is a part of the base game code, not something in the mod.)

I'm stumped as to how this can apparently be so computationally expensive.

Is it called very many times? The method is called at various points in the Entity update routine, which runs every 1/20 of a second - so with potentially thousands of entities there may be upwards of several thousand calls to this method per second. **But** not only are there countless other methods being invoked just as often, many of those are more complex than a field reference, and yet have nowhere near the apparent impact of this one.

Sometimes, mods inject or replace the code of certain pre-existing methods using ASM bytecode manipulation. Could this be happening here - maybe some other mod is replacing the simple `return this.inWater;` with a much more complex calculation? Well, I removed every other mod to check, and the results didn't change.

Another idea - in some classes, this method is overriden (it belongs to the `Entity` class, but the `Squid` class overrides it with something more complex). Maybe these overriden methods are the culprit? But it doesn't seem so - VisualVM reports the expensive invocations as `Entity.isInWater()`, not `Squid.isInWater()`.

So I have no idea what's going on here, and it surely seems nonsensical.

Any suggestions for how to investigate this further? Is it possible that it could be a bug in VisualVM itself, or some JVM error? (Counter to this idea is that I've never seen a similar problem with any other method.)

- The 5-10% figure is sampled from a particular server running this mod, therefore it may vary. But I can say that on running a local server I found similarly astonishing figures. Within the same order of magnitude.

Comment: Could the mod that you're profiling be the one that's using OW2 ASM to inject into that method?

Comment: I did double-check just in case I'd forgotten, but no, I haven't used any ASM on that method.

Comment: Hmm. What happens if you profile with Forge but no mods? What about completely vanilla, not even Forge?

Comment: Also, is your mod responsible for any of the calls to that method?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica my findings:
1. It doesn't seem to be happening on the local server any more. Neither with plain Forge nor the mod. Weird. In fact the method doesn't show up at all in the profiler, presumably because it's so quick, which is what I would have expected

Comment: 2. The method is called by my mod entities but it's only in the course of the normal update routine that all entities share. And (on the server with the issue) both mod and vanilla entities show this outsized computation time, e.g. the chicken's call hierarchy includes isInWater() in three places for 1.0% of overall, and sheep likewise at 0.4%.

Comment: Re 1., are you saying that your problem fixed itself but you're not sure how?

Comment: It seems so - I might not have been clear in the original post, but this problem is occurring on a remote server (professionally hosted) and the local server is a test one running on my own machine, which I'm no longer seeing the problem on.

Comment: So you used to see the problem on both servers, and now you don't see it on your local one but you do still see it on the remote one?

Comment: Did you rebuild/reupload/etc. something on your local machine to make it stop happening? Can you do the same on the remote one?

Comment: Yes that's right, and I didn't knowingly change anything on the local server. When I tested a few days ago it had the same problem, now it doesn't. Sorry, I know that's not very helpful... I'm starting to wonder if it's some specific problem on the remote server but I can't imagine what it might be.